# What does "extends JPanel" mean?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, extends

I have a class called UserInterface. In the code `public class UserInterface extends JPanel`, does "extends JPanel" mean that there is a JPanel within the JFrame (the JFrame is the application window) or does it mean something else?

Also, if it means that there is a JPanel within the JFrame, how can I access the JPanel (for example, set its background colour)?

Comment: I recommend studying the basics of Java before moving on to UI development.

Answer (score 1):

`extends` in Java means *is-a*. So your class is a JPanel; it's inheritance; a fundamental part of OOP.

Since your class is a JPanel, if you want to set it's background color somewhere inside the class you'd just do `setBackground(yourColor)` from outside would be `ui.setBackground(yourColor)` assuming of course that you named the instance `ui`.

[JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)s are not the same as [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)s if that's what you were getting at.